# JS/JQ How can I append element below to the div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For example. Here's some html code:

```
<div class="elements-block">
</div>
```

I have to put there two elements but that way should put second element below of first.

```
$(".elements-block").append("<p>First element</p>");
$(".elements-block").append("<p>Second element</p>");
```

After this my html code should look as this:

```
<div class="elements-block">
    <p>Second element</p>
    <p>First element</p>
</div>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/

Comment: You need `First element` first or at the second?

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal I want to append a several items but that way it would reverse (not from first to third, but from third to first)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `prepend` instead of `append`

```js
$(".elements-block").append("<p>First element</p>");
$(".elements-block").prepend("<p>Second element</p>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="elements-block"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That's what I was looking for

Comment: @JoeDoe That's great. Please accept it as an answer if it solved your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

> HTML:

```
<div class="elements-block">
<p></p>
</div>
```

> J-Query:

```
$(".elements-block p").append("<p>First element</p>");
$(".elements-block p").append("<p>Second element</p>");
```